# Google Cloud SQL proxy randomly crashes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using Cloud SQL proxy on one of my compute engine instances for secure connection to MySQL. I have configured a Service account with a generated JSON file and also I have started up cloud SQL proxy on the instance and it's working properly.

But I had 2 random crashes from Friday to Saturday, when it just stopped to connect Back-end and DB. I had to start the cloud SQL proxy connection again on my own manually and afterward, it worked again properly.

Command with wich I am starting: ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=somename:us-central1:othername=tcp:3306 -credential_file=/home/project/projectName/someName.json &

Could someone advise me of possible places that could make cloud SQL proxy go down or where I can find out logs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the verbose flag to see more details about it. Something like

```
/cloud_sql_proxy -verbose=true -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:3306
```

Actually, the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#tips) recommends to capture the output in a log file. "Also, the output from the proxy can help you diagnose connection problems, so it can be helpful to capture in a log file".

In [this](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-sql-proxy-installing-as-a-service-on-gce/) blog you can find more information about this and useful tips such as how to debugging problems using the Cloud SQL Proxy.